# building json by using mysql fetch result

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, json

hello i want to use my mysql result to build the json objects. my first query is fetching parent menu and another query is fetching child menu so i am going to put my child menu result under the parent menu.. i want to know what is wrong with my code and how to correct

```
<?php
    $selectparentMenu=mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`item_name`,`menu_type`,`parent` FROM `epic_master_menu` where parent=0");
    //echo $myfetch=mysql_fetch_array($selectMenu);
        if(mysql_num_rows($selectparentMenu)>1) {
    while($fetchparentMenu=mysql_fetch_array($selectparentMenu)) {
         //echo 'parent id is' .$parentId=$fetchparentMenu['id']. '<br/>';
        // echo 'parent name is' .$parentId=$fetchparentMenu['item_name']. '<br/>';


         $selectchildMenu=mysql_query("SELECT `id` , `item_name` , `menu_type` , `parent` FROM `epic_master_menu`
    WHERE parent >0 AND `menu_type` = 'item' AND `parent` ='".$fetchparentMenu['id']."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($selectchildMenu)>1) {
         while($fetchchildMenu=mysql_fetch_array($selectchildMenu)) {

             $textjson = '{
    "dataSource": [{
            "id": "", "text": "Select All", "expanded": "true", "spriteCssClass": "rootfolder", "items": [
                {
                    "id": "'.$fetchparentMenu["id"].'", "text": "'.$fetchparentMenu["item_name"].'", "expanded": true,"spriteCssClass": "folder", "items": [
                        { "id": "'.$fetchchildMenu["id"].'", "text": "'.$fetchparentMenu["item_name"].'", "spriteCssClass": "html" },
                        { "id": "'.$fetchchildMenu["id"].'", "text": "'.$fetchparentMenu["item_name"].'", "spriteCssClass": "html" },
                        { "id": "'.$fetchchildMenu["id"].'", "text": "'.$fetchparentMenu["item_name"].'", "spriteCssClass": "image" }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }]
    }';

             }  }

         /* $fetchMenu['item_name'];
           $fetchMenu['menu_type'];
           $fetchMenu['parent'];*/
        //print_r($fetchMenu);
        } }
```

// my json data is

```
 $textjson = '{
"dataSource": [{
        "id": 1, "text": "My Documents", "expanded": "true", "spriteCssClass": "rootfolder", "items": [
            {
                "id": 2, "text": "Project", "expanded": true,"spriteCssClass": "folder", "items": [
                    { "id": 3, "text": "about.html", "spriteCssClass": "html" },
                    { "id": 4, "text": "index.html", "spriteCssClass": "html" },
                    { "id": 5, "text": "logo.png", "spriteCssClass": "image" }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 6, "text": "New Web Site", "expanded": true, "spriteCssClass": "folder", "items": [
                    { "id": 7, "text": "mockup.jpg", "spriteCssClass": "image" },
                    { "id": 8, "text": "Research.pdf", "spriteCssClass": "pdf" }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 9, "text": "Reports", "expanded": true, "spriteCssClass": "folder", "items": [
                    { "id": 10, "text": "February.pdf", "spriteCssClass": "pdf" },
                    { "id": 11, "text": "March.pdf", "spriteCssClass": "pdf" },
                    { "id": 12, "text": "April.pdf", "spriteCssClass": "pdf" }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }]
}';
```

Comment: why not make use of `json_encode()` ?

Comment: would you please clarify it i mean where and how should i implement

Answer (score 4):

Instead of creating your own version.. you could simply make use of [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/json_encode)

```
while($fetchchildMenu=mysql_fetch_array($selectchildMenu))
 {
      $somearr[]=$fetchchildMenu;
 }

$jsonData = json_encode($somearr);
echo $jsonData; //<---- Prints your JSON data
```

Comment: i have my own json format and i just want to insert my query record on it

Comment: so format the array to your format and then use json_encode on it

Comment: @Sachin, Creating your own version is a pretty headache. Do like `Robert` mentioned.

Comment: this is my json formta

Comment: i know how to encode the array into json.. but i am actuly not getting  how to build an array that will display in my json format

Comment: @shankar actuly i am making an checkbox tree for my project there i need a preformated json if suppose i create an array and if i encode it then it must be look like my preformated json..

Answer (score 0):

Its much easier to use the included json functions from PHP. Here you can use [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to create a json string from an array.

```
$childArray = array();

while($fetchchildMenu=mysql_fetch_array($selectchildMenu)) {
   $childArray[] = array(
       'id' => $fetchchildMenu['id'],
       'text' => $fetchchildMenu['text']
   );
}

$jsonDataChilds = json_encode($childArray);
echo $jsonDataChilds;
```

Comment: i have edited my question i have put my json format there so if i want to use array then how i need to build the array by using the same format of json.

Comment: To avoid mistakes in your schema its easier to build an array and convert it to the final json string using the json functions. Don't reinvent the wheel its not necessary.

Comment: i just want to know how to build an array which will show me my required json format..